# Robot framework Parallel test execution on two different machines

Tags: robotframework

I'm automating web application using RobotFramework with selenium2library.

I'm looking for parallel test execution of two different test suites on two different machines (Browsers too).

Is it possible to achieve via seleniumgrid like below?

```
       Robot test suite
  (TWo different testcases)
           ____
          |    |Hub
          |____|

 ____                    ____
|    |                  |    |
|____|                  |____|
Node 1 machine          Node2 machine
```

Thanks in advance

Regards

Vallinayagam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, first you must run hub

```
java -jar <selenium.jar> -role hub 
(optional port f.e.: -port 4444)
```

Then you can run up nodes:

```
java -jar <selenium.jar> -role webDriver (for selenium 2 library) -hub http://<selenium hub ip>:4444/grid/register 
(optional parameter remoteHost f.e.: -remoteHost http://127.0.0.1:5555)
```

Nodes can be run separately and be specified by additional parameter -remoteHost . This host can be used in selenium keyword **Open Browser**

```
Open Browser | url | browser=ff | alias=None | remote_url=False
```

Example:

```
${REMOTE_DRIVER}=    Set Variable    127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub   
Open Browser    www.google.com    ff    None    ${REMOTE_DRIVER}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it works for me when ${REMOTE_DRIVER} =  http://<HUB Machine IP ADDRESS>:5555/wd/hub

Comment: I have tried this and its was not parallel executing from nodes. one after another.. why is that happening??